# Grails & Mysql Connection mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: mysql, grails

here is i have problem with Mysql Db Connection to Grails Project, I have created this db with name cars from terminal everything is okey. But when i try to run my app i get this error.

```
| Error Error occurred running Grails CLI: mapping values are not allowed here
 in 'reader', line 107, column 17:
                 url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
                    ^
 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

and here is my application.yml file

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username: "root"
    password: "1234"


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
             url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

And here is build.gradle file i already add to dependencies this one

```
runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you have an extra space at line 17. Inside the brackets.

```
        dbCreate: update
        [ ]url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
```

You can test your yml file at this site: http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Try like this:

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username: "root"
    password: "1234"


environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars'
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars'
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: none
            url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars"
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Comment: I've tested it with the same result: just remove the space in front of the "url" in the "test" block. Or revove the "test" block for further debugging.